# Drupal7 - User/Registration customizing

Tags: 7, users

Please any one help me to how I can do customizing User/Registration page in Drupal 7. For example I have a select option for user group, suppose if I choose 'others' option ’ then user is allowed to create new group in separate text box.

I'm new to Drupal. Please anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 you can use **[Select (or other)](https://drupal.org/project/select_or_other)** module for your requirement

> **Select (or other)** module : Provides a new Forms API element which is a select/radios/checkboxes element that has an 'other' option. When
>   'other' is selected a textfield appears for the user to provide a
>   custom value.

Comment: Great.. I will try this